# Publishing a preprint while having another related work on review

Tags: publications, preprint

**Preliminaries**

As coauthor, I sent a work *X* to a reputable journal. The work *X* deals with two problems *A* and *B*. The reviewers asked for some minor clarifications/corrections. I performed them, and sent back the corrected version to the journal.

For related studies, two methods *M1* and *M2* are commonly used (and many times were compared with each other). Part *A* of *X* is an insight on *M1*.

Working on *X* lend me to use similar techniques to provide the same insight for *M2*. I've been working on this for few weeks, in my private time, and got very interesting results.

Both works are linked in that those insight let compare *M1* and *M2* in an categorical way (so the new work needs to use the final results of part *A*, citing its preprint). Also, a conclusion of *M1* which is automatically derived form *X* is stressed (I did not added it to *X* as I naively missed it before). If it matters, the new work also explores *M1* and *M2* in new ways.

I wish to make a preprint (that I've already written) immediately because:

**1.** I found that the results are very significant.
 **2.** *X* is almost an invitation to perform the more relevant results of my new work. I've seen relatively recent works in top journals (of the field) comparing *M1* and *M2*, so I think that it is very plausible. (The main difference with my work is that, previous works are numerical comparisons of few samples (due to cost) and I have found the analytical expressions).

**Question**

What should I do?

I fear that making this preprint goes in detriment of the decision of the reviewers of *X*, for example, asking for adding those news discoveries (in case that they found the preprint). Although I found it unreasonable as the author list is different and I suppose that they should give a review of the work sent (*X*). Even more, they already gave they positive feedback.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wish to [publish] a preprint (that I've already written) immediately because...What should I do?

Make the preprint available.

> I fear [publishing] this preprint [is detrimental to the ongoing review] of X

I don't see why this should be the case. How can any result that builds upon X be detrimental to X? Surely such results are favourable to X, since they'd show that X is useful?

You could cite the preprint in X, especially if it helps address reviewer's concerns.